# How to put the ajax response/result into variable php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Can I put the ajax response into variable? So that I can echo the variable into php?

ajax.php

```
<script>
function random_no(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(result){
            $("#random_no_container").html(result);//the result was displayed on this div
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

On my sample code above, i call the query result from test.php and the result was displayed on the div but i want to put that on the variable and echo the variable. something like the code below

```
<?php echo $variable;?>
```

Can this possible? please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859401/converting-javascript-variable-to-a-php-variable

Answer (score 2):

You can't PHP is executed on server and Ajax from the client so you cannot assign PHP variable an ajax response.
Once a PHP is rendered on the client side it is just HTML no PHP code.

Comment: Hello my friend. Thank you for your response. So what should I do? what is the option of this?

Comment: This is what i want to happen. I want to display or put the ajax response inside the javascript ----> data: [<?php echo $variable; ?>]

Comment: It's not possible as on client you cannot execute PHP codes. Why you want that? If you want any server side processing you can send to another PHP page and get that result again from Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function random_no(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            success: function(result){
               var result_val=result;
               alert(result);            
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hello Friend. I got this. but i dont want to use alert. i want like this ------------> series: [{
    name: 'Present',
    data: [<?php echo $variable?>
    ]
   },

Answer (score 0):

As @dev answered , you need to execute server and client code differently ! I answered here for your need variable only .But in developing website, should not use javascript in php tag `<?php ?>`

#### ajax.php

```
<div id="random_no_container">
    <?php
     if(isset($_GET['variable'])) {
        $variable = $_GET['variable'];
        echo $variable;
     } else {
        echo "<script>sessionStorage.setItem('stopped',0);</script>";
     }
     ?>
</div>
<script>
var stopped = sessionStorage.getItem("stopped");
if(stopped == 0) {
    random_no();
}
function random_no(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(result){
            sessionStorage.setItem("stopped",1);
            //$("#random_no_container").html(result);//the result was displayed on this div
            location.href = "ajax.php?variable="+result;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```